# how to remove duplicated object (string)from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have two json arrays with the some same object, what i want is to have a json from these two json which is not includes duplicated value, for example this is my jsons:

```
json1=["one","two"];
json2=["one","two","three","four"];
```

the result must be:

```
result=["three","four"]
```

do you know how to have to make it, thanks

Comment: Are they arrays of strings, or arrays of objects? Your example shows strings, but your title says objects.

Comment: arrays of string

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
function myFilter(arraySmall, arrayBig){
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayBig.length; i++) {
    if (arraySmall.indexOf(arrayBig[i]) === -1){ //ie. if item not exists in arraySmall
      result.push(arrayBig[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

You can just call `myFilter(json1, json2);`

Comment: This only works if `json2` is always bigger than `json1`.

Comment: It works fine even if `json2` is smaller. The arg names could be better, like (`bannedWords`, `orignalWords`)

Comment: @KevinBoucher This doesn't work even in that case, just assume arrays `[1]` and `[2]`, result should be `[1, 2]` and the above algorithm won't produce this result no matter what ordering you choose as it is simply far from correct one.

Comment: @MatusDubrava, you might have misinterpreted Jan's original question. In your example, the desired result should be: `[2]`. If we follow your suggestion, you'd be looking for : ```function myFilter(arraySmall, arrayBig){
  var _all = arraySmall.concat(arrayBig);
  var _obj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < _all.length; i++) {
    _obj[_all[i]] = "whatever";
  }

  return Object.keys(_obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using a reduce and filter function:

```
const json1 = ["one","two"];
const json2 = ["one","two","three", "four"];

const result = json2
  .reduce((acc, cur) => acc.indexOf(cur) > -1 ? acc : acc.concat(cur), json1)
  .filter(item => json1.indexOf(item) === -1 || json2.indexOf(item) === -1);

console.log(result); // ["three", "four"]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code 
this is a function which basically subtracts the 2 array and returns the resultant array

a1 and a2 are the 2 array

a is an empty array which has true value in all the a1[index]

a1 = [1,4,5];
a = [0,1,0,0,1,1];

1 = true
like this

now we check id any a2[index] is present in the a

if a2 = [1,3];

then a[a2[atanyindex]] will be a = [0,1,0,0,1,1];

..........................................................^   1
and if this happens delete that element

add the remaining elements to the diff array 
and the diff array is the subtraction of 2 array aka you required answer

```
function arr_diff(a1, a2) {

    var a = [], diff = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        a[a1[i]] = true;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
        if (a[a2[i]]) {
            delete a[a2[i]];
        } else {
            a[a2[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    for (var k in a) {
        diff.push(k);
    }

    return diff;
}
```

Comment: _"Here is the code"_ doesn't teach the OP or future users. Provide some detail on what you used and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the arrays and then filter the duplicates out by comparing `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` for each item:

```js
const json1 = ["one", "two"];
const json2 = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

const withoutDupes = [...json1, ...json2].filter((item, idx, array) => {
  if (array.indexOf(item) === array.lastIndexOf(item)) {
      return item;
  }
});

console.log(withoutDupes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. Use `Array.prototype.reduce` to pick all the elements that are in the first array and not in the second one. Then use it the same way to pick all the elements that are in the second one and not the first one. And finally, merge those two results.

```js
const _removeCommon = (xs, ys) =>
  xs.reduce((acc, v) => ys.includes(v) ? acc : acc.concat(v), []);

const removeCommon = (xs, ys) =>
  [..._removeCommon(xs, ys), ..._removeCommon(ys, xs)];

const json1=["one","two"];
const json2=["one","two","three","four"];

console.log(removeCommon(json1, json2));
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Jan**, try the below code.

> It uses **filter()** and **concat()** methods defined on arrays.

```
json1=["one","two"];
json2=["one","two","three","four"];

var arr1 = json1.filter((key) => {
       if(json2.indexOf(key) == -1) 
            return true
       else 
            return false
})

var arr2 = json2.filter((key) => {
       if(json1.indexOf(key) == -1) 
            return true
       else 
            return false
 })

result = arr1.concat(arr2)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use concat and filter pretty simply.

```
function noDupes(arr1,arr2){
  return arr1.concat(arr2).filter((item,index,arr)=>{
    if(arr1.includes(item)&&arr2.includes(item))
        return false
    else
        return item
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if you don't know/care which array is longest. Not very short, but easy to read and understand.

```
function myFilter(arr1, arr2) {

const combined = [...arr1, ...arr2]

const seen = new Set()

combined.forEach(item => {
  if (seen.has(item)) {
    seen.delete(item)
  } else {
    seen.add(item)
  }
})

return Array.from(seen)

}
```

First we use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to easily combine both arrays into a single array.

Then we create a new [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which will be like a bucket we toss our values into.

Next we'll use forEach to loop over the combined array and ask 
"Have we seen this value before? If so, let's delete it because that means it's not unique; otherwise, let's add it to the set."

Finally, we use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to turn our set into an array and return it.

Answer (score 0):

This provides you with 3 results based on the type argument.

(1) 'uniq': no duplicates
(2) 'duplicate'
(3) 'not_duplicate'

```
let json1 = ['one', 'two']
let json2 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

function uniq_n_shit (arr1, arr2, type) {

  if (!type || type === 'uniq' || type === 'unique') {

    return [...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))]

  } else if (type === 'duplicate') {

    let concat = arr1.concat(arr2)
    return concat.filter(function (obj, index, self) {
      return index !== self.indexOf(obj)
    })

  } else if (type === 'not_duplicate') {

    let concat = arr1.concat(arr2)
    let set = [...new Set(concat)]
    let remove = concat.filter(function (obj, index, self) {
      return index !== self.indexOf(obj)
    })

    for (let r = 0; r < remove.length; r++) {
      let i = set.indexOf(remove[r]);
      if(i !== -1) {
        set.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    return set

  }
}

console.log(uniq_n_shit(json1, json2, null)) // => [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ]
console.log(uniq_n_shit(json1, json2, 'uniq')) // => [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ]
console.log(uniq_n_shit(json1, json2, 'duplicate')) // => [ 'one', 'two' ]
console.log(uniq_n_shit(json1, json2, 'not_duplicate')) // => [ 'three', 'four' ]
```